# How to upload a spring web app running on Tomcat into cPanel?

Tags: java, spring, web, cpanel

I made a java Spring web application running on a Tomcat server and I want to deploy it on cPanel in order to have an official website. How can I do that ? I tried to upload the .war extension of my app in public_html folder, but when I access the website the structure of the folders is shown. How to solve this problem , what are the steps should I take in order to upload my app into cPanel ?

Comment: You already asked this question [once](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36945773/1240557), or maybe even [twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942807/how-to-upload-a-spring-web-application-to-cpanel).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should install tomcat

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Introduction+to+Tomcat#IntroductiontoTomcat-HowtoinstallTomcat

And after this read this manual for deploying

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Deploy+Java+Applications#HowtoDeployJavaApplications-HowtodeployJavaWARpackages